# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression even though nothing is missing

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting the *java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression* in the following statement. I do not see any typo or an extra comma anywhere. Why could I be getting this error?

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select password from logininfo where username = " + uname);
```

Where uname is a String variable.

Comment: Learn to use parameters to pass in values and you will never have this particular problem again.

Comment: You are missing single quotes around `uname`. But as Gordon Linoff said, you do want to use parameters instead of concatenating the query string.

Comment: @GMB uname is a String variable

Comment: `rs = st.executeQuery("select password from logininfo where username = '" + uname + "'");`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error perhaps because the value of `uname` is empty (zero-length) string, hence getting your DB server to try and run the query...

```
select password from logininfo where username =
```

... which is... well... missing an expression after the `=` operator.

As the commenters already pointed out, use parameters (a.k.a. "bind variables" in terms of some DB servers), i.e. execute the statement...

```
select password from logininfo where username = ?
```

... with *binding* the value of `uname` variable to the query's first parameter.